# setAtrribute call on a tag element does not work

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am a new learner in HTML5, CSS and Javascript. So my apologies if my question is very basic. I am working on a responsive navigation menu. When the width of the browser is greater than 500 a vertical navigation bar is present. Once the size of the screen page is less than 500(on mobile phone for example) the horizontal navigation bar should be hidden and instead the hamburger icon shows up. When clicked on the hamburger menu a vertical navigation bar will be shown underneath of the hamburger icon. 
But the problem is when I call setAttribute("visibility", "visible") or setAttribute("visibility", "hidden") on navigation bar it does not work. I am not sure why. setAttribute is called either the time of load of the screen or when the hamburger icon is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/page-main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/footer.css">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- fonts -->
  <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body  onload="hideORShow()">
    <header>

    <nav id="navigation-links" class="navbar navigation-box">
      <div class="col-1of6 nav-item">
        <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./index.html">Home</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-1of6 nav-item" >
        <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./spring-summer.html">Fall</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-1of6 nav-item">
        <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./fall-winter.html">Winter</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-1of6 nav-item">
        <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./leather.html">Leather</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="open-slide">
      <a href="#">
        <svg id="hamburgur-icon" onClick="openSlideMenu()">
          <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
          <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
          <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav" >
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" onClick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
      <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./spring-summer.html">Fall</a>
      <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./fall-winter.html">Winter</a>
      <a class="main-nav-item-page-index" href="./leather.html">Leather</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my javascript file:

```
var hamburgerMenu = document.getElementById('hamburgur-icon');
var slidingMenu = document.getElementById('side-menu');
var navigationBox = document.getElementById('navigation-links');


function hideORShow(){
  if(width > 500){
    console.log("Inside of hideOrShow function - Window width is greater than 500px, hiding hamburger");
    hamburgerMenu.setAttribute("visibility","hidden");
    slidingMenu.setAttribute("visibility","hidden");
  }
  else{
    console.log("Inside of hideOrShow function - Window width is less than 500px, hiding hamburger");
    navigationBox.setAttribute("visibility","hidden");
    hamburgerMenu.setAttribute("visibility","visible");
  }
}

function openSlideMenu(){
  console.log("hamburger btn clicked");
    slidingMenu.setAttribute("visibility","visible");
    slidingMenu.setAttribute("background-color","red");
}

function closeSlideMenu(){
  console.log("close btn clicked");
    slidingMenu.setAttribute("visibility","hidden");
}
```

I see in the chrome debugger that the visibility attribute is changed after the event being fired, but I still don't see visual change in the browser. For example the vertical nav bar underneath of the hamburger icon is still present when I click the close button. 
I would appreciate any tip.

Comment: "Attribute" is a DOM thing - attribute of element. "Property" is a CSS thing - style property.

Comment: Thanks c-smile, I didn't know. I don't why people in here give -1. So who new learners should go to ask question then?

Comment: @user1836957 maybe because you should do a small research before asking the question, you will for sure get the anwser.

Comment: @Temani Did you just gave me a negative point? if yes please reverse it because now I am in the danger of not being able to ask questions at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is when I call setAttribute("visibility", "visible") or setAttribute("visibility", "hidden") ...

Visibility is a CSS style, not an element attribute. That's why it's not working. Try replacing any lines that look like:

```
navigationBox.setAttribute("visibility","hidden");
hamburgerMenu.setAttribute("visibility","visible");
```

With:

```
navigationBox.style.visibility = "hidden";
hamburgerMenu.style.visibility = "visible";
```

The latter actually sets the `visibility` CSS style for the element, whereas the former sets an attribute on the element (and visibility as an attribute does nothing on it's own).

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to change are CSS styles, not HTML attributes. The attribute in question is the `style` attribute, but there's an easy way to do this in JS:

For example,

```
slidingMenu.style.visibility = "visible";
slidingMenu.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: good! Please approve this answer (or CRice's) to close the question